# Android java touch battery icon

Tags: android

I have a weird problem. My android app runs fine I can open other programs and then reopen my app and it has no problem. When i touch the battery icon it closes and it resets all of my data. Does anyone know whats going on?

The basic setup of my app is from this [tutorial](http://oster-lundqvist.com/karsten/?p=4886). I'm having some problems when the application leaves focus it seems to drop out and crash randomly.

Answer (score 0):

After searching through my code I found that my `UpdateThread` for my custom surface view was not restoring itself properly. So it was pausing and then not copying its values to a new thread when the app got focus again.